# Send email notification on data set refresh fail using boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-quicksight

I have a Lambda function with this in it:

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
account = sts_client.get_caller_identity()['Account']
qs_client = boto3.client('quicksight')

qs_client.create_ingestion(
    DataSetId=full_data_set_id,
    IngestionId=ingestion_id,
    AwsAccountId=account,
    IngestionType=data_set['ingestionType'])
```

This works fine. However, the Quicksight UI has this:

[image: quicksight UI refresh options]

Is there a way using boto3 to make it so that if a refresh of the data set fails, it sends this automated email? Is the only way to do this to make another Lambda function to monitor each ingestion that is created?

To add to the context of the question, the use case is that I'm creating all of my team's quicksight resources via CDK and thew SDK, so setting the schedules by hand and using the UI is out of the picture, there's literally hundreds of data sets.